# Compactness of the set $S=\{\sin(2^nx)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $$S=\{\sin(2^nx)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ in the metric space $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ of Lebesgue square integrable  functions. On $[-\pi,\pi]$ with metric defined as $$ d(f,g)=[\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f-g)^{2}dx]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ Then which of the following are true?

$1.$ $S$ is bounded.

$2.$ $S$ is closed.

$3.$ $S$ is compact.

I tried as follows .

According to me set $S$ is bounded as $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[(\sin(2^nx)-\sin(2^m )]^2 \leq 4\pi.$ For closeness let $f_n\rightarrow f$ where $f_n\in S$. Then $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[(f_n-f )]^2\rightarrow 0. $ Now how to proceed further. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for edit ......

Comment: Hint: the members of $S$ are orthogonal, and the distance between them is always ...

Comment: If possible solve .... thanks for reply .... so according to you Because of distance it’s closed.

Comment: @RobertIsrael and what about compactness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the elements of $S$ have norm equal to $\sqrt{\pi}$, so $S$ is bounded. 
Distinct elements of $S$ are orthogonal in $L^2$, so given two distinct elements $f_i=\sin(2^i x)$ and $f_j = \sin(2^j x)$, you have $d(f_i,f_j)= \sqrt{2\pi}$. This means that there are no accumulation points in $S$, so the set is closed.
The set is not compact since you can consider a cover which is made of open balls of radius $<\sqrt{\pi}$ around each point of $S$. All these balls are disjoint so you cannot find any finite subcover, as required in the definition of compactness.

Comment: Thank you very much ...

Comment: sir can I say that this metric space will be discrete metric space because of distance .

Comment: Usually you define a discrete metric on a set as the metric which gives to each pair of distinct points a distance of 1. Here the metric on $S$ induced by $L^2$ is basically the same thing but gives a distance of $\sqrt{\pi}$.

However you can say that the topology induced on $S$ by $L^2$ is the discrete topology, meaning that each subset of $S$ is an open set.

Comment: Yes sir thanks a lot for clear it ...

Comment: Sir how the Norm is equal to $\sqrt {π}$ ? Here d(f,g) is the norm right?